# SignInManager track signIn url Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have followed [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html) instructions to develop projects with separate authentication endpoint.
I have 2 separate web-applications. One is a Asp.Net Core + Identity Server 4 authentication endpoint. Another application is a client which is configured to authorize via authentication endpoint. Is there a way I can track what kind of web request does the SignInManager send when the following line of code is being executed?

```
 await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

I have used Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger 4 and I haven't seen any requests so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not produce any web traffic. You can check out what that method does over [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L253). But in short, it tells the HttpContext to issue a cookie if sign in is successful.

In other words, it will issue a cookie when that controller method ends. Check out the browser cookies and this will give you an idea of what is going on.